# Can PolyUtil method be executed in Foreground Service

Tags: android, google-maps

Basically I want to execute the Polyutil method in a ForegroundService.is it possible that the Polyutil method works in a Foreground service If I provide it with latlng,and the polygon?

```
contains = PolyUtil.containsLocation(userLatCircle, userLngCircle, savedGeofenceList, true);
```

Comment: sure, it works...

Comment: it works basically I forgot to implement a thread,now is working . thanks for the support !

Comment: you are welcome